# Angular ng-options track by overriding ng-model default option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-options iterating over an object, the key of this object is the value I need the ng-options to be set to.

I set the ng-model in my controller to default the select box.

Using `track by` breaks the ng-model default, however stopping `track by` removes the issue but introduces another where the default of the select box is no longer the key of the object.

How can I get around this issue?

The HTML I am using is as follows

```
<select 
     class="form-control" 
     ng-change="flightNumber = airline[0]" 
     name="airline" 
     id="airline" 
     ng-model="airline" 
     ng-options="airline for (airline, flights) in orderedFlights track by airline">
</select>
```

In my controller I have the following:

```
var flights = {
    "Airline": {

    },
    "Airline 2": {

    },
    "-- No Airline Selected --": [
        {
            unselected: true
        }
    ];
}

$scope.orderedFlights = flights;
$scope.airline = flights["-- No Airline Selected --"];
```